# NN Classifiers: Can inputting a known normal example alongside the example to classify assist classification?

Tags: classification, neural-networks

As an (overly simplified) example, lets say I have some samples of audio, and each sample only has either sine, square, or triangle waves. The waves will appear as either normal or abnormal.

The goal is to classify each wave in the sample as normal or abnormal. The problem is that a normal triangle wave and a abnormal sine wave look very similar, and our model is struggling to learn features to differentiate the two.

Would it be beneficial to pass an example normal wave from elsewhere in the sample as an additional input? Like telling the model: "for this sample, a normal wave looks like this: ^--^--".

I'd like to know if additional context information like this can help a classifier make a correct decision. I haven't been able to find any papers relating to this, so any would be appreciated.

Comment: do you know what wave-type each sample is in (sine/square/triangle) at test time? do all the waves have the same period and phase? even if not i suspect it would be pretty easy to normalize them to have roughly the same period and phase -- would you agree?

Comment: The example is not my actual problem, just a demonstration. I've edited to clarify. Normalizing is not an option for my dataset. At test time there will be at least one known normal wave available, and the goal is to identify the rest of the waves as normal/abnormal.

Comment: do you know what wave-type each sample is in (sine/square/triangle) at test time? otherwise how can you find a matching normal wave as additional input?

Comment: A normal wave would be selected by a human

Answer (score 2):

It might be beneficial to split the problem: you might train a first network, that differentiates sine, triangle and square waves. Then, for each class, you may train another model, that operates solely on one class and checks, whether the data are normal or not.